# Oracle SQL query to get sales by date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to write an SQL query that will provide me sales broken into date ranges, but it is a bit above my SQL knowledge.

I have a table of date ranges by customers as follows:

```
Cust Product startdate   enddate
-----------------------------------
 A   123    2011-01-01  2011-12-31
 A   124    2011-01-01  2011-05-01
 A   125    2011-01-01  2011-05-01
 B   123    2011-01-01  2011-03-01
 B   124    2011-01-01  2011-03-01
 C   125    2011-02-02  2011-05-01
```

and sales stored as follows:

```
Cust Product    date      qty
-----------------------------------
 A   123    2011-04-08     1  
 A   124    2011-01-01     12 
 A   125    2011-05-01     2
 B   123    2011-01-04     3
 B   124    2011-02-01     5
 C   125    2011-03-01     80
```

The results should look something like:

```
Cust Product startdate   enddate     qty
-----------------------------------------
 A   124    2011-01-01  2011-02-01    12
 B   123    2011-01-01  2011-02-01    3
 B   124    2011-02-02  2011-03-01    5
 A   123    2011-03-02  2011-05-01    1
 C   125    2011-03-02  2011-05-01    80
 A   125    2011-05-02  2011-12-31    2
```

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: what have you try?

Answer (score 0):

I made the example in MySQL because Oracle server was down. But query is the same.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bcb9/3)**

```
SELECT R.*, S.*
FROM dRanges R
JOIN Sales S
  ON S.`date` >= R.`startdate`
 AND S.`date` <= R.`enddate` 
 AND S.`Cust` = R.`Cust`
 AND S.`Product` = R.`Product`
```

But you have to be carefull ranges doesnt overlap, otherwise you can have same Sales value appear on two ranges

**EDIT** Please explain the logic here

[image]

Comment: That'll be MySQL, I think

Comment: You are right @DavidAldridge, Couldnt make the demo in oracle because online server was down. But query is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have overlapping date ranges. Each range represents an 'estimated sales' for a catalogue and a customer may have a number of catalogues running for different periods.    I am looking to break all ranges into smaller 'sub ranges' and get sales for these.

Comment: If you have two date ranges `[A,B] and [B,C]`  where you put sales for day `B`? Show me examples and how you want to handle those case and I improve my answer.

Comment: Looking at a basic example, if I had two date ranges for the same customer and product of 1/1/16 to 30/06/15 and 1/3/16 to 31/7/16 I would want to get sales for the following ranges.

Comment: 1/1/16 to 28/2/16, 1/3/16 to 30/06/15 and 1/7/16 to 31/7/16.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: i think you mean `30/06/16` ?? But if that is your desire then doesnt matter. The problem is if you sum the total from each range will be larger than the total, because the sales apear on different ranges.

Comment: Sorry it should be 16 not 15!  I am trying to break the sales up into the three sub-ranges. Will this not be the same total as the range 1/1/16 to 31/7/16?

Comment: Sorry, Now Im confused in what you want. I told you if you have ranges like this `[A,B] and [B,C]` and you have sales for date `B` will appear on both ranges. What you do instead of using B you use `B1 = yyyy/mm/dd 23:59:59  and B2 yyyy/mm/dd+1 00:00:00'` and make your ranges `[A,B1] and [B2,C]`

Comment: I understand your comments about using B1 and B2. My data is already set up as ranges A to C and B to D. I need the query to get sales for ranges A to B1, B2 to C1, C2 to D. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Not a chance. Did you try my query? Show me a picture or something. Current data and expected result.

Comment: Ok, I see something now, but still not clear. See my picture and explain your logic.

Comment: Using the above data, I am trying to split into periods of 1/1/11 to 1/2/11, 2/2/11 to 1/3/11, 2/3/11 to 1/5/11 and 2/5/11 to 31/12/11.

Comment: I then want to get the total sales per customer for each product during each period.

Comment: Splitting the periods allows me to account for times when there is an overlapping period for the same product and customer.  If a product appears in two instances of the same period for the same customer, I can divide the sales by 2 and share them out.

Comment: Looks you arent good at explaining question, gl with your question